# Upload file size in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to upload the 11 mb mp3 file using do_upload in codeigniter.

My upload function :-

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/mp3';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3';
$config['max_size'] = '1024*20';
$this->load->library("upload", $config);
$image_data = $this->upload->data();
```

My  php.ini

```
post_max_size : 32M
memory_limit : 128M
max_execution_time :120
```

But I cant' upload 11mb mp3 file . But less than 8 mb its working fine. Please help how can I fix this .

The error in the php error log is :-

```
{"file_name":false,"error":["<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.<\/p>"]}
```

Comment: The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file.

Comment: Look at your `php error log` for error messages from this script. What are they?

Comment: {"file_name":false,"error":["<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.<\/p>"]}

Comment: my php config:-post_max_size : 32M
           memory_limit : 128M
           max_execution_time :120

Comment: Edit your question and add the error message there

Comment: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Comment: Also check `upload_max_filesize =` is large enough and make sure `post_max_size` is greater that `upload_max_filesize =`

Comment: You may need to check if the application recognizes the mimetype of the file that is being uploaded. Adding a new mimetype to config/mimes.php may fixed the issue

Comment: post_max_size : 32M and  upload_max_filesize :- 512M may be it cause issue

Comment: As files and other `<input>` fields are all part of the `post_max_size` then it should always be `post_max_size = (max_file_uploads*upload_max_filesize+something for normal input fields)` This allows you to upload more than one file or rather the max number of files allowed of up to the `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: @RiggsFolly good mathematical formulation

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi Thanks, but like you have said earlier, and the error message denotes, it looks more like a mime type issue to me. But I am not sure why the error message looks like JSON so maybe thats a red herring

Comment: `$config['max_size'] = 1024 * 20;` - Pay attention there are no quotes surrounding value since file upload class expects integer, not string. Although you can pass `20480` at first place. [Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller).

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3';
```

This line mean you can only upload files in mp3 format.

This error means your file is not mp3 format.
change

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3';
```

to

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```